# pcap.h and libpcap: char vs u_char

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap

In pcap.h, extensive use has been made of `u_char` which is (indirectly) defined as `typedef unsigned char u_char;`.

In particular, pointers to a packet are always declared as `u_char * packet`. I don't understand, why use `unsigned char` rather than just `char`? The pointer to a packet will  be used to extract data from the packet by pointer arithmetic and casting to various other types so it shouldn't make any difference whether we use `char` or `unsigned char`?

For example from `man pcap_loop`

```
   typedef void (*pcap_handler)(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *h,
                               const u_char *bytes);
```

Here, `const u_char *bytes` is the packet. Why use `u_char` rather than `char` for raw byte data?

Also, I would imagine that using a pointer of type `const u_char *` is for historic reasons? Wouldn't it be better to use `const void *bytes`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for certain why Van and Steve decided to go with `u_char *` rather than `void *`, but the reason may have been that what libpcap hands your callback routine is a pointer to an array of bytes - not of signed 8-bit integers, so they chose to explicitly flag the characters as unsigned - and that accessing the array requires subscripting/pointer arithmetic, which is *not* guaranteed to be supported by `void *` (NOTE: "gcc and gcc-compatible compilers support pointer arithmetic on `void *` does not mean that it's guaranteed to be supported by all compilers).